# Notify inside a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

My App, execute a call to a remote db, so periodically makes a call to read json response, and if it's a particular value, it should send a notify. It makes his work correctly, but opens the activity that send the notify. What I should want to realize is that inside control cicle, the app gives notify and only when user clicks on it, open activity with complete message.Is it possible?
Here is my code

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
String userid, datareq;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("My_App",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String userid = prefs.getString("userid", "");
    String datareq = prefs.getString("datareq", "");

    String[] params = new String[2];
    String[] result = new String[2];
    params[0] = userid;
    params[1] = datareq;


    try {
        result = new TaskControl(context.getApplicationContext()).execute(params).get();
        if (result[1].equals("-1")) {
            //failed

        } else {

   // Here i call NotificationView.class, but i should want send
   // directly the notify
            Intent msg = new Intent(context, NotificationView.class);
            msg.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(msg);

        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

This is EDITED class using your helps

```
   public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
String userid, datareq;
private Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("Beauty_App",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String userid = prefs.getString("userid", "");
    String datareq = prefs.getString("datareq", "");

    String[] params = new String[2];
    String[] result = new String[2];
    params[0] = userid;
    params[1] = datareq;


    try {
        result = new TaskControl(context.getApplicationContext()).execute(params).get();
        if (result[1].equals("-1")) {
            //failed
            Toast.makeText(context, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            // if i use notify, app stops

         Notify ("Msg","Title");


        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.scanner,"New Message", System.currentTimeMillis());
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,NotificationView.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);

        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(9999, notification);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your code from `NotificationView.Notify()` method to the else part where you are starting `NotificationView` activity.

And to open this activity only if user clicks on the notification create pending intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationView.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And then set this intent using `NotificationCompat.Builder` like this:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx).setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent).build();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. Unfortunately it isn't clear enough form me. If i move code from NotificationView.Notify inside AlarmReceive.clas i obtain many errors. Then, where i must use Notification notification = ...etc? Could you be more clear? Thanks

Comment: Make sure you are importing the required packages. Also use `context` in place of `this`

Comment: Sure, I have just tested your code following this steps, but if i put the code `private void Notify(String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage){
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);` inside AlarmReceiver getSistemservice is redflagged

Comment: Use, `context.getSystemService()`

Comment: Perfect. Now no red flag errors. I have moved that block of code inside alarmreceiver, but when i use notify ("msg","title") it stops. I think it need notificationcompat.builder, but i don't know how use it

Comment: `NotificationCompat.Builder` is required to set the `pendingIntent`. Set it as shown in my answer using `setContentIntent()` method